# Identifying fonts in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts

I'm trying to identify the fonts embedded in a PDF. I'm using the command

`pdffonts file.pdf`

However, I get this output

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
RXMDSF+font000000001e9cd877          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
EANDYD+font000000001e9cd877          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     12  0
```

How come the font names are encoded? Is there a way to retrieve the names of the fonts?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to identify the OS used.  I assume you're on a *nix.  In Windows, you can copy-paste to Word, then click in the interesting text to see its font.  Alternately in Windows, you can copy and use a utility to look at the raw data on the clipboard.  Lastly on Windows, Adobe Acrobat can probably identify the font on an opened PDF.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: will copy-paste to Word work if you do not already have the typeface installed? That is, will it identify the typeface even if a substitute is being used to render?.

Comment: @Yorik , good point, PDFs can have embedded fonts so that the OS and Word don't have the font available.  I've never used a PDF font extractor, but this old question might be the answer needed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files

Answer (score 3):

So that naming scheme indicates that the fonts listed are partial embedded subsets. The way it works is to use a prefix of six uppercase letters (random), the plus sign, and the postscript name of the base font.

It looks like the base name of the font is "font000000001e9cd877." This may be mangled by the encoding software used, but it also may be the "internal name" of the font or a derived one because the field was not entered by the font designer, especially if it is a custom font or was converted using e.g. FontForge.

See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156429/what-is-the-scheme-of-fonts-naming-in-pdfs-generated-by-latex-and-other-software